# Unflatten array into a new document and add to the output

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose

My MongoDB document has an array property with item similar to the original documents.

I'd like to unwind the array property and add it after parent:

Current structure:

```
{
    _id: "1",
    name: "Test1,
    children: [ 
      {         
         _id: "2",
         name: "Test2" 
      }, {
         _id: "3",
         name: "Test3" 
      }]
}
```

The end result should be:

```
[{
    _id: "1",
    name: "Test1
},
{
    _id: "2",
    name: "Test2
},{
    _id: "3",
    name: "Test3
}]
```

I've tried using **$unwind** but keeps unwinded in the same childer property:

```
{
   path : "$children",
   preserveNullAndEmptyArrays : false // optional
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the example documents and the outcome you expected, you could try:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
             { "$project": { tmp : { 
                          "$concatArrays":[ 
                                         "$children" ,
                                         [ {_id:"$_id", "name": "$name"}]
                                        ]
                                 }
                        }
             }, 
             { "$unwind" :"$tmp"}, 
             { "$replaceRoot" : {newRoot: "$tmp"}}]
)
```

The [$project operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) is to [combine arrays using $concatArrays operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concatArrays/), combining all entries in array `children` and the root level `_id` and `name` into a temporary field called `tmp`.

```
 {"_id":1,"tmp":[ 
                 {"_id":2,"name":"Test2"},
                 {"_id":3,"name":"Test3"},
                 {"_id":1,"name":"Test1"} ]      
 }
```

After the above stage, we would have an array of three elements. Utilising [$unwind operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) we can unwound the array elements:

```
{"_id":1,"tmp":{"_id":2,"name":"Test2"}},
{"_id":1,"tmp":{"_id":3,"name":"Test3"}},
{"_id":1,"tmp":{"_id":1,"name":"Test1"}}
```

Lastly, we use [$replaceRoot](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/) to bring the sub-document to the root level and remove `tmp` field.

```
{"_id":2,"name":"Test2"},
{"_id":3,"name":"Test3"},
{"_id":1,"name":"Test1"}
```